# Confused how this double recursion works

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, recursion, merge

I was given a problem to **sort an array using merge sort**. I am following a course and I am confused on how their solution works. I understand most of it but the double recursion part is what I don't understand. I was creating console logs and I can't figure out how I'm getting those printed results. Any help would much appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
var mergeSort = function (nums) {
  if (nums.length <= 1) return nums;

  let mid = Math.floor(nums.length / 2);
  let left = nums.slice(0, mid);
  let right = nums.slice(mid);

  left = mergeSort(left); //RECURSION
  right = mergeSort(right); //I'M CONFUSED HOW THIS SECOND RECURSIVE CALL WORKS
  console.log("left", left);

  let block = [];
  let l = 0;
  let r = 0;

  while (l < left.length && r < right.length) {
    if (left[l] < right[r]) {
      block.push(left[l]);
      l++;
    } else {
      block.push(right[r]);
      r++;
    }
  }

  if (l < left.length) {
    block = block.concat(left.slice(l));
  } else if (r < right.length) {
    block = block.concat(right.slice(r));
  }
  return block;
};
console.log("result", mergeSort([3, 4, 2, 1]));   //TEST CASE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if this will help:

If we add some logging to your function, we can generate this output:

```
mergeSort ([3,4,2,1])
  left:
    mergeSort ([3,4])
      left:
        mergeSort ([3])
        ==> [3]
      right:
        mergeSort ([4])
        ==> [4]
      merge ([3], [4])
    ==> [3,4]
  right:
    mergeSort ([2,1])
      left:
        mergeSort ([2])
        ==> [2]
      right:
        mergeSort ([1])
        ==> [1]
      merge ([2], [1])
    ==> [1,2]
  merge ([3,4], [1,2])
==> [1,2,3,4]

result: [1,2,3,4]
```

The recursive call doesn't end anything.  It simply returns a value to whatever called it.  At the root, that is the initial call to `mergeSort`.  For the inner calls, it's the call to sort the left half or to sort the right half.

So, in each call to `mergeSort`, where we don't hit our base case, we will split the remaining array in half(-ish) and recursively call it to sort the left half, then recursively call it to sort the right half, then merge the two halves back together, which is straightforward because both are now sorted.

This is one of those things that you might discover with playing cards.  If you want to sort the whole randomly-shuffled deck, one of the best ways is to split it in half, sort each half and merge them by putting the two sorted piles in front of you, continually pulling the smallest value of those showing to add to your main pile.  But to sort one of those half decks, the best way is to split it in half, sort...  And thus the recursion.  I personally will do this several levels deep.  When I get down to three or four cards, I sort them by inspection.

This snippet shows how I added the logging:

```js
const log = (indent, message) => 
  console.log (Array(indent * 2).fill(' ').join('') + message)


var mergeSort = function (nums, indent = 0) {
  log (indent, `mergeSort ([${nums}])`)
  if (nums.length <= 1) {
    log (indent, `==> [${nums}]`)
    return nums;
  }
  
  let mid = Math.floor(nums.length / 2);
  let left = nums.slice(0, mid);
  let right = nums.slice(mid);

  log (indent + 1, 'left:')
  left = mergeSort(left, indent + 2); 
  log (indent + 1, 'right:')
  right = mergeSort(right, indent + 2); 

  let block = [];
  let l = 0;
  let r = 0;

  log (indent + 1, `merge ([${left}], [${right}])`)
  while (l < left.length && r < right.length) {
    if (left[l] < right[r]) {
      block.push(left[l]);
      l++;
    } else {
      block.push(right[r]);
      r++;
    }
  }

  if (l < left.length) {
    block = block.concat(left.slice(l));
  } else if (r < right.length) {
    block = block.concat(right.slice(r));
  }
  log (indent, `==> [${block}]`)
  return block;
};

console .log ('', `result: [${mergeSort([3, 4, 2, 1])}]`)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this version could help you to see how calls are executed:

```
var mergeSort = function (nums, stackNumber, calledFromSide) {
  if (nums.length <= 1) return nums;

  let mid = Math.floor(nums.length / 2);
  let left = nums.slice(0, mid);
  let right = nums.slice(mid);
  console.log(`stackNumber: ${stackNumber}, calledFromSide: ${calledFromSide}, left:${left}, right:${right}`);
  left = mergeSort(left, stackNumber + 1, 'left'); //RECURSION
  right = mergeSort(right, stackNumber + 1, 'right'); //I'M CONFUSED HOW THIS SECOND RECURSIVE CALL WORKS


  let block = [];
  let l = 0;
  let r = 0;

  while (l < left.length && r < right.length) {
    if (left[l] < right[r]) {
      block.push(left[l]);
      l++;
    } else {
      block.push(right[r]);
      r++;
    }
  }

  if (l < left.length) {
    block = block.concat(left.slice(l));
  } else if (r < right.length) {
    block = block.concat(right.slice(r));
  }
  return block;
};
console.log("result", mergeSort([3, 4, 2, 1], 1, 'root'));   //TEST CASE
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped I'm just wondering when exactly does the second recursion get called? Isn't it when the first recursion hits the base case and block gets returned?